# Index + Match with multiple criteria and merged cells

Tags: excel

I have this fabulous excel workbook where I have some product data which we get from databases. I have four magnificent variables I put in. Year, Quarter, Week and Products.

Im trying to do a index + match lookup for quantity sold but I only receive error #N/A. But I should get 1967 since thats what we sold. We didn't sold NA.

[image: My Excel Workbook Problem]

I'm using the this formula in E6.

```
=INDEX(C12:AH15;MATCH(1;($C$9=C9:AH9)*($E$3=C10:AH10)*($E$4=C11:AH11)*($E$5=B12:B15);0))
```

Is it possible to fix this formula to recieve the correct value, is merged cells problem?

**EDIT:** 
After good suggestion I put values in every cell, not glamorous as before, but formula will still not detect the correct value.. any ideas what could cause the problem now? It shouldn't be the merged cells at least.

[My revised workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tWtl.png)

A lot of thanks in advance!

Comment: The merged cells make this type of lookup nearly impossible without helper rows.  Get rid of the merged cells and put the data in each cell.

Comment: Also to fill in Index(range,row,column) you need to find the right row by matching in column B as well as the right column by matching in rows 9, 10 and 11.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your wise words. It's sad, it was such a beautiful layout. I tried to add data in every cell instead. I updated the table in my question above but still get error :(. Maybe this worksheet is beyond saving... :,(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your formula so you are using IFs rather than the "*" wildcard.  This formula will work without the merged cells:

```
=INDEX($C$12:$AH$15,MATCH($E$5,$B$12:$B$15,0),MATCH($E$4,IF($C$9:$AH$9=$E$2,IF($C$10:$AH$10=$E$3,$C$11:$AH$11)),0))
```

This is an array formula, so you will need to press CTRL + Shift + Enter for it to work correctly.  Here is how it should look (My example only goes to column Y.  The formula above is the same, but goes through column AH as does your original formula):

[image]

With the merged cells will be more difficult.  Depending on how your spreadsheet works, I would add in some logic around the "Week" row but that would highly depend on how the spreadsheet works.  It looks as if columns are added to the left, so if the cells all the way to the right have the same starting point you may be able to add in some logic based on that starting point.